# How to set fixed width for labels in chartjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, bar-chart

I have one dataset with multiple labels in my bar chart. When bar chart has more labels, width of label shrink for each.

I want to set fixed width for every window in my chart. For example dark stick for every label should be same fixed width size no matter how many window exists.

[image]

Thank in advance.

Comment: did any solve this problem, i am also facing the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Is it a request to have the vertical axis have a fixed width?

There is a way to do this:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      afterFit: function(scaleInstance) {
        scaleInstance.width = 100; // sets the width to 100px
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: this configuration does not provide fixed width for window. I updated my question. Please take a look. Thank you for your helping

Comment: did any body solve this issue ? i am also facing the same problem