# Prevent y-axis labels from being cut off

Tags: javascript, chart.js

My chart y labels are cut off and by trying different solution found on stackoverflow like adding spaces in labels or setting layout padding did not solved the problem.

The code

```js
const optionsTotali = {
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      displayColors: false,
      mode: "index",
      intersect: 0,
      callbacks: {
        label: function(context) {
          return "€" + context.parsed.y.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,').replace(/[,.]/g, m => (m === ',' ? '.' : ','));
        }
      }
    },
  },
  scales: {
    y: {
      grid: {
        display: false
      },
      ticks: {
        min: 0,
        beginAtZero: true,
        sampleSize: 1,
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
          return "€" + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

const ctx = document.getElementById("chartTotali").getContext('2d');
const chartTotali = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [
      "08:00",
      "09:00",
      "10:00",
      "11:00",
      "12:00",
      "13:00",
      "14:00",
      "15:00",
      "16:00",
      "17:00",
      "18:00",
      "19:00",
      "20:00"
    ],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Totale €",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: '#0084ff',
      borderColor: '#0084ff',
      borderWidth: 2,
      pointBackgroundColor: '#0084ff',
      data: [
        "17089.36",
        "394279.52",
        "514863.02",
        "540198.74",
        "379222.06",
        "8793.42",
        "79.58",
        "116379.41",
        "444580.43",
        "506663.36",
        "457947.28",
        "138158.94",
        "398.46"
      ],
    }]
  },
  options: optionsTotali
});
```

```css
.card-chart {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 0.0625rem solid rgba(34, 42, 66, .05);
  border-radius: 0.2857rem;
}

.card {
  background: #27293d;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
}

.card .card-body {
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

.card-body {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.card-chart .chart-area {
  height: 220px;
  width: calc(100% + 30px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.7.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="card card-chart">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
        <h5 class="card-category">Totale vendite</h5>
        <h2 class="card-title">Totali</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="chart-area">
      <canvas id="chartTotali" width="1563" height="220" style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 220px; width: 1563px;"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sampleSize` property in your y axis config is the culprit, since you put it to `1` it only looks at the first tick for the length that it can use. But other data in your array is way larger so it wont fit. Removing this property or making it a bigger number so it would sample more ticks will resolve your behaviour (removing will give most consistent results).

```js
const optionsTotali = {
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      displayColors: false,
      mode: "index",
      intersect: 0,
      callbacks: {
        label: function(context) {
          return "€" + context.parsed.y.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,').replace(/[,.]/g, m => (m === ',' ? '.' : ','));
        }
      }
    },
  },
  scales: {
    y: {
      grid: {
        display: false
      },
      ticks: {
        min: 0,
        beginAtZero: true,
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
          return "€" + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

const ctx = document.getElementById("chartTotali").getContext('2d');
const chartTotali = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [
      "08:00",
      "09:00",
      "10:00",
      "11:00",
      "12:00",
      "13:00",
      "14:00",
      "15:00",
      "16:00",
      "17:00",
      "18:00",
      "19:00",
      "20:00"
    ],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Totale €",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: '#0084ff',
      borderColor: '#0084ff',
      borderWidth: 2,
      pointBackgroundColor: '#0084ff',
      data: [
        "17089.36",
        "394279.52",
        "514863.02",
        "540198.74",
        "379222.06",
        "8793.42",
        "79.58",
        "116379.41",
        "444580.43",
        "506663.36",
        "457947.28",
        "138158.94",
        "398.46"
      ],
    }]
  },
  options: optionsTotali
});
```

```css
.card-chart {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 0.0625rem solid rgba(34, 42, 66, .05);
  border-radius: 0.2857rem;
}

.card {
  background: #27293d;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
}

.card .card-body {
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

.card-body {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.card-chart .chart-area {
  height: 220px;
  width: calc(100% + 30px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.7.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="card card-chart">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
        <h5 class="card-category">Totale vendite</h5>
        <h2 class="card-title">Totali</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="chart-area">
      <canvas id="chartTotali" width="1563" height="220" style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 220px; width: 1563px;"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Damn i had lot of other charts without that problem in the same page but just didn't noted that property

Answer (score 2):

You can handle it with the `sampleSize: x,` property. You can removed then the y-axis will show correctly. Many thank to @LeeLenalee!

```js
const optionsTotali = {
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      displayColors: false,
      mode: "index",
      intersect: 0,
      callbacks: {
        label: function(context) {
          return "€" + context.parsed.y.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,').replace(/[,.]/g, m => (m === ',' ? '.' : ','));
        }
      }
    },
  },
  scales: {
    y: {
      grid: {
        display: false
      },
      ticks: {
        min: 0,
        beginAtZero: true,
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
          return "€" + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

const ctx = document.getElementById("chartTotali").getContext('2d');
const chartTotali = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [
      "08:00",
      "09:00",
      "10:00",
      "11:00",
      "12:00",
      "13:00",
      "14:00",
      "15:00",
      "16:00",
      "17:00",
      "18:00",
      "19:00",
      "20:00"
    ],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Totale €",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: '#0084ff',
      borderColor: '#0084ff',
      borderWidth: 2,
      pointBackgroundColor: '#0084ff',
      data: [
        "17089.36",
        "394279.52",
        "514863.02",
        "540198.74",
        "379222.06",
        "8793.42",
        "79.58",
        "116379.41",
        "444580.43",
        "506663.36",
        "457947.28",
        "138158.94",
        "398.46"
      ],
    }]
  },
  options: optionsTotali
});
```

```css
.card-chart {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 0.0625rem solid rgba(34, 42, 66, .05);
  border-radius: 0.2857rem;
}

.card {
  background: #27293d;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
}

.card .card-body {
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

.card-body {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  background: ;
}

.card-chart .chart-area {
  height: 220px;
  width: calc(100% + 30px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.7.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="card card-chart">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
        <h5 class="card-category">Totale vendite</h5>
        <h2 class="card-title">Totali</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="chart-area">
      <canvas id="chartTotali"  style=""></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does only fix the problem if there isnt a verry big value after the 10th property, best solution would be to no use it

Comment: @LeeLenalee Thank you very much for the important and correct advice. I really didn't know that and I have just learned something new. Merci! I have removed `sampleSize` and adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After testing your code, the problem seems to come from this part :

```
    callback: function(value, index, values) {
      return "€" + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
    }
```

My guess is : since you change the labels in an async callback, chart.js doesn't know which width to aply anymore and goes with the width of the first label...

You could resolve this by setting the width like this :

```
  afterFit: function(scaleInstance) {
    scaleInstance.width = 100; // sets the width to 100px
  }
```

Source here : [How to set fixed width for labels in chartjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61665138/how-to-set-fixed-width-for-labels-in-chartjs)

Comment: While this solves the problem it is not a scalabele solution, you either give up a lot of space you now waste or you still can have a problem if the numbers become extrememely big and your width needs to be increased.

Comment: @LeeLenalee I guess you could estimate the width based on the min-max values beforehand

Answer (score -1):

You can use the sampleSize property

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).